# Are the Living Greyhawk materials considered first party creations?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dnd-3e, greyhawk, organized-play

Are the Living Greyhawk materials considered first party creations, and why or why not?

Despite being created by non employee volunteers, the materials were endorsed by WoTC, thus I hear conflicting claims about if the materials are or are not first party.

For those not aware, Living Greyhawk ("LG") was a massively shared Dungeons & Dragons living campaign administered by RPGA that ran from 2000 to 2008. The campaign setting and storyline were based on Gary Gygax's World of Greyhawk setting, and used the Dungeons and Dragons Third Edition (later v3.5) rules. During the lifespan of the campaign, more than a thousand adventures were published, and these were played by tens of thousands of players around the world.

The LG campaign differed from previous shared-world campaigns in one important respect: thirty of the regions from World of Greyhawk were linked to real-world areas; volunteers from these real-world locations then assumed responsibility for the storyline and administration of that particular region. In return, the real-world location was the only place where one could play adventures belonging to that region. Any adventures set outside these thirty regions were "core" adventures that could be played by anyone anywhere.

Comment: Edition? Heck, *system?* Link to example?

Comment: I don't think many of the Regional Triad sites are still up and functional, so links might be problematic.

Comment: Instead of this superbroad question that's unlikely to have a satisfactory, unequivocal answer, maybe ask about a specific game element that you want to incorporate into your campaign? Likewise, it may be worth explaining in the question *why* whether or not these are considered first-party material is even important. (I mean, at this point in the game's lifecycle, organized play has been dead for over a decade. Honestly, given WotC's own record with its game, any DM who's using *3.5* now should be evaluating stuff case-by-case anyway.)

Comment: But this is exactly what I need to know. The reason is simply that I want to reference it correctly as which it is, first party or other, and understand why that is so. If there is no definitive answer then that should BE the answer instead of voting down the question. Sometimes, knowing that there isn't an answer is the best answer, and the community needs those kinds of questions and answers too.

Comment: Thing is, asking *Is everything official?* mandates that the answer assess all *thousand* adventures or whatever. By narrowing this to one item, a good answer should address why a particular element is official or not thereby giving you a baseline. (And *I* didn't downvote the question, and I don't think anyone has since you updated the tags.)

Comment: Not really? Why do all that work when one can just hunt for a statement made about the program's 1st party status as a whole? If the program is 1st party, then would all of the official content be likewise?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. the official L5R organized play for 5th had some adventures that *do* have a canon influence (Wedding at H. Castle), and where how players solved it in general shaped canon lore, but there were certain adventures that in canon *never happened* (The Ronin adventure is set like that).

Comment: I request suggestions. Without restricting too much, how can I improve this question?

Comment: @Trish But is the canonical status of an adventure the same as a first party source?  WG7 is certainly first-party, but definitely not canon.  Those seem like different questions.

Comment: @Kirt exactly what I tried to illustrate! FFG was publisher of the game and the adventures at that time (now it is edge). The wedding adventure was played for some time and all GM returns to FFG were evaluated and as a result, the crane marriage became canon. The ronin adventure did only collect feedback on the ronin schools it was used to test for.